# Inserting Norwegian letters into SQLite db through java program

Tags: java, database, sqlite, encoding

I'm trying to fill an SQLite database with data in my java program.

The data is read from an excel file using Apache POI. I have no trouble inserting the data into the db using normal methods. 
However, when I check the database manually with the shell, all the Norwegian characters æ,ø,å are not displayed correctly. Whenever I fill out the database manually through the shell, they are displayed as they should.
Also, when printing out a java string in console containing these characters, they are displayed correctly.

The problem must occur when an action like this is performed:

```
String sql = "insert into db(name) values (æøå)";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

I have tried

```
byte[] b = sql.getBytes("utf-8");
sql = new String(b, "utf-8");
```

to no avail.

Any idea how to remedy the situation?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you set your database encoding (using pragma) before inserting data or creating tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple solution for you: Let Java and the SQLite driver do everything for you. You don't have to care about encodings and escaping of parameters.

How that is possible: Use a PreparedStatement:

```
String name = "æøå"
PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into db(name) values (?)");
prepStmt.setString(1, name);
prepStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Furthermore this code fragment is secure against SQL injection attacks.

BTW: The second code fragment you posted is totally useless, it does nothing. Converting a String to byte[] and back to String does not change a single bit of the String.